# Pre-define complicated math operators

Tags: macros, math-operators

### Problem

I am trying to find a easy way to write Rademacher complexity so that I just need to write different index, function and constraint every time. Like defining partial derivative I previously read somewhere

```
\newcommand*{\pdv}[3][]{\ensuremath{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3}}}
```

[image]
I defined it as

```
\newcommand*{\RC}[1][2][3]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{E}_S[\mathbb{E}_\sigma \sup_{#2}\frac{1}{#1}\sum_{i=1}^{#1} \sigma_i #3]}}
```

But it does not work.

Could anyone help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Not `[1][2][3]` but just `[3]`

Comment: Thank you. So here `[3]` does not mean the *place* it should appear but *number* of different signs?

Comment: Yes, it denotes the number of arguments to the macro being defined.

Comment: @Mr.Robot If you want something like `[1][2][3]`, you can use the TeX command `\def`. For example: `\def\RC#1#2#3{\ensuremath{\mathbb{E}_S[\mathbb{E}_\sigma \sup_{#2}\frac{1}{#1}\sum_{i=1}^{#1} \sigma_i #3]}}` (unchecked).